# How to move browser window to the top of an spry accordion tab?

Tags: javascript, accordion, spry

I have a spry accordion in my site that has varying heights. Some are larger than the screen - when I click on the next tab the spry content area expands but shows only the content at the very end of the spry content area window.

to explain:

```
    |[tab 1 ....            ]|<hidden area
    | content 1              |<hidden area
    | content 1              |<hidden area
     ------------------------
    | content 1              |<visible area 
    | content 1              |<visible area
    | content 1              |<visible area 
    | content 1              |<visible area
    | content 1              |<visible area 
    | content 1              |<visible area 
    |[tab 2 ....            ]|<visible area
     ------------------------
    | content 2              |<hidden area
    | content 2              |<hidden area
```

when I click tab 2 this happens

```
    |[tab 2 ....            ]|<hidden area
    | content 2              |<hidden area
    | content 2              |<hidden area
     ------------------------
    | content 2              |<visible area 
    | content 2              |<visible area
    | content 2              |<visible area 
    | content 2              |<visible area
    | content 2              |<visible area 
    | content 2              |<visible area 
    |[tab 3 ....            ]|<visible area
     ------------------------
    | content 3              |<hidden area
    | content 3              |<hidden area
```

when this is what I want to happen when I click on any tab

```
     ------------------------
    |[tab 2 ....            ]|<visible area
    | content 2              |<visible area
    | content 2              |<visible area
    | content 2              |<visible area 
    | content 2              |<visible area
    | content 2              |<visible area 
    | content 2              |<visible area
     ------------------------
    | content 2              |<hidden area 
    | content 2              |<hidden area 
    |[tab 3 ....            ]|<hidden area
    | content 3              |<hidden area
    | content 3              |<hidden area
```

When I click any tab I want the page to reposition it self so that the tab heading goes to the most top part of the browser, how can I do this?

I hope this question makes sense as I thought real hard about it don't want to lose any rep!

Answer (score 0):

This goes in the `<head>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function goToAnchor(anchor) {
  location.href = "#"+anchor;
}

function spryTabAnchor(anchor)
{
  setTimeout("goToAnchor('"+anchor+"')", 500); //The 500 milliseconds is a delay so you still have the animation.
}
</script>
```

This is the anchor:

```
<div class="AccordionPanelTab" onclick="spryTabAnchor('pan2')"<a id="pan2"></a>Tab</div>
```

Comment: If somebody knows of a better way... Let me know!

Comment: how would I use this method to anchor to 50px from the top of the page?

Comment: Just use: `window.scrollTo(0,50);`